# PHP tricky cumulative loop

Tags: php

I want to build a simple script with a loop that does some cumulative calculating. Obviously i'm doing something wrong, but i can't seem to figure out how to resolve my problem. Any tips?

```
$a = 100; // money
$b = 0.03; // interestrate
$c = $a * $b; //interest
$sum = $a + $c;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i ++) {
        echo "Total after $i year(s): $sum += $c";
        echo "</br>\n";
}
```

offtopic: no idea why i'm not allowed to use any more obvious question titles like "PHP cumulative calculation loop"

Comment: Show what your expected results are and what your actual results are

Comment: Pro tip sidenote: Change `</br>` to `<br/>` --- `</br>` is not a valid tag.

Comment: Why not just do `$sum += $c * 10`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to calculate compound interest, so there are both logical and syntactical mistakes in your code...Please try the code..

```
$a = 10000; // money
$b = 3; // interestrate, generally its  percentage

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i ++) {
    $c = $a * $b/100; //interest
    echo "Total after $i year(s): ". $a += $c;
    echo "</br>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are printing: (plus and equal signs). Mathematical problems need to be outside of quotes because they are being evaluated as strings.

`Total after 1 year(s): 40 += 30` etc.

when using

```
echo "Total after $i year(s): $sum += $c";
```

change it to:

```
echo "Total after $i year(s): " . $sum += $c;
```

***Output will now give you:***

Total after 1 year(s): 70
Total after 2 year(s): 100
Total after 3 year(s): 130
Total after 4 year(s): 160
Total after 5 year(s): 190
Total after 6 year(s): 220
Total after 7 year(s): 250
Total after 8 year(s): 280
Total after 9 year(s): 310
Total after 10 year(s): 340

***Instead of:***

Total after 1 year(s): 40 += 30
Total after 2 year(s): 40 += 30
Total after 3 year(s): 40 += 30
Total after 4 year(s): 40 += 30
Total after 5 year(s): 40 += 30
Total after 6 year(s): 40 += 30
Total after 7 year(s): 40 += 30
Total after 8 year(s): 40 += 30
Total after 9 year(s): 40 += 30
Total after 10 year(s): 40 += 30

---

***Pro tip sidenote:***

Change `</br>` to `<br/>` --- `</br>` is not a valid tag.

Comment: _perfectly put up_ ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$a = 10; // money
$b = 3; // interest
$c = $a * $b;
$sum = $a + $c;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i ++) {
        $sum += $c;
        echo "Total after $i year(s): $sum";
        echo "</br>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change for loop

```
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i ++) {
    $sum += $c;
    echo "Total after $i year(s): $sum";
    echo "</br>\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`+=` is not being recognized. Change to:

```
$a = 10; // money
$b = 3; // interestrate
$c = $a * $b; //interest
$sum = $a + $c;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i ++) {
        echo "Total after $i year(s): ".$sum += $c;
        echo "<br/>\n";
}
```

Comment: [Concatenation operator has higher precedence than the assignment operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). This will not work.